# What type of paint can be used over oil-based primer?

Tags: paint, repainting

I don't remember what brand or type of paint was used in my kitchen about 9 years ago. One wall has developed some cracks and the paint has been coming off in brittle "chips" My kitchen gets very steamy a lot. Same paint on other 3 walls no problem...I have a gallon of oil primer still good from a previous small job I intend to use.

What paint will be best for use over the oil primer and have "flexibility ( not be "brittle")?? All the walls in my house were once painted with "calcimite" I discovered oil paint no longer made does the best for coverage and long term durability

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a "modern" oil-base like Kilz or Cover Stain, I'd say you're on the right track. Oil-based primer offers the best adhesion for your paint.

> My kitchen gets very steamy a lot.

My bet is you have a flat latex paint on the walls. I would repaint with a semi-gloss enamel (can be latex). The semi-gloss will resist the moisture better than flat paint.